# Differences between install via artisan and composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I found that web.config is included when I install Laravel with:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

but not when I install Laravel using the Laravel installer, with:

```
laravel new blog
```

(as per https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation)

I've subsequently found a few other differences e.g. devDependencies versions in package.json, some config settings in broadcasting.php, cache.php, database.php.

Can anyone explain to me what is responsible for this difference? Is one install method 'better' than the other?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Hi @Delena-Malan - I considered the web.config tag to be relevant because I wanted to know why it was present in one install method and not the other. The presence of web.config is helpful for developers like me who are targetting IIS. Other Laravel users might be wondering where it is and might search on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between both commands is that the `composer` command uses packagist to get the latest package from GitHub the first time or a cached version, while `laravel new blog` downloads a zip file from the Laravel server which has the latest version and uses that. Both commands run the so called 'after install' scripts, creating an environment file and setting the application key.

When you don't want a cached version but a new one using composer, run `composer clear-cache` first, to delete the local cache composer creates.

If you want to see the difference for yourself, compare the `composer.json` of the base Laravel project (https://www.github.com/laravel/laravel) and the `NewCommand.php` file in the `src` directory of the Laravel installer (https://www.github.com/laravel/installer)

#### Edit

After running both commands, the only difference I could really find was the order in which some things are done, but both generate a working system. Fun thing I noticed is that `laravel new project` comes with a `yarn.lock` file, but without a `readme.md` and `composer composer create-project` vice versa.

Comment: Thanks Douwe - it looks like Composer is going for 

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip

which does contain /public/web.config

and Laravel Installer is going for:

http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip

which doesn't contain /public/web.config

Comment: @ChrisPeckham No worries! I added a part about composer caching some stuff. If you feel that this answer is correct, don't hesitate to mark it as accepted.